# Using OAuth 2 to access the google form API in C#

Tags: c#, google-forms-api

I need help creating a Google Form in C#. I can't find how to login with oauth 2. Can someone provide an example or link to how to do it?

I looked on the internet and found nothing. I also tried to use `forms.create`, but that wasn't a function. Any help would be greatly Appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.